# List all the shares in a network

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, samba, network-share

I am running Linux and in my network we have got lots of systems with samba shares. Is there any way so that I could get all the samba shares information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`smbtree` will show you all clients and shared folders in a tree like structure

Answer (score 3):

You can use a command like:

```
$ smbclient -L server_addr -Uusername
```